# What is the difference between 때 and 에?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference  between these two sentences?
1   저녁에 봐요.
2   저녁때 봐요.

Are 때 and 에 interchangeable?

Comment: I'm Korean and I always try to use `때에` instead of `때`. I always consider `때` in the middle of a sentence as the short form of `때에`.

Answer (score 4):

In here `~에` means `at` so `see you at night`
`~때` in here means `when` so `see you when night` will sounds weird in English.

For example, `배고플때` is `when you hungry`, `슬플때` is `when you sad`

It is interchangeable sometimes but in my example it is not changeable.

Answer (score 2):

The two things are definitely not interchangeable.

때 is a noun by formal grammar, but for convenience you can think of it as *when* or *if* (i.e. a conjunction) when it introduces a clause (by coming after it).  For example:

> 심심할 때는 이거나 봐.  (*When you are bored, look at this*--pointing to a book perhaps.  는 here suggests that boredom would probably not be the only condition for the whole time. 나 here suggests the book being offered is perhaps not a big deal.)

Or,

> 애가 심심해 할 때는 이거나 보여 줘. (*When the child is/acts bored, show him this.*)

For an example without 는,

> 빨간 불일 때 길을 건너다.  (*To cross the street when it is red light*.)

When 때 introduces a substantive for an event or occasion, you can think of it as *at*, *on*, or *about* (i.e. a preposition), again just for convenience.  For example:

> - 회의 때 보다.  (Lit. *To see at the time of the conference*, but meaning *to see at the conference*)
> - 예배 때 보다.  (*To see at church service.*)

I suspect this may ultimately come from:

> - 회의 할 때 보다.
> - 예배 볼 때 보다. (Here the first 볼 means to *observe* or *attend*.)

but have no basis to say so.  Only, it might help you to relate the two constructions if you remember that "substantive + 때" and "substantive + verb + 때" convert to each other readily for the most part.

The exception to this convertibility would be things like 설 때 (*around New Year's*) or 방학 때 (*during break from school*).

To introduce a substantive for a time, use 에.

> - 아침에 보다. (*To see in the morning.*)
> - 오후에 보다. (Lit. *To see between noon and midnight*, but practically *to see between noon and sundown*.)
> - 주말에 보다. (*To see in the weekend.*)
> - 늦은 시간에 보다. (*To see at a late hour.*)

The following will all sound bad, in the respective senses above.

> - <strike>아침 때 보다.</strike>
> - <strike>오후 때 보다.</strike>
> - <strike>주말 때 보다.</strike>
> - <strike>늦은 시간 때 보다.</strike>

The only exception I can think of is:

> 저녁 때 보다.  (*To see in the evening.*)

I.e. 저녁 as a reference to a time can take 때.

One complication arising from an ambiguity. 아침 and 점심 are not only a time, but also a meal, i.e. an event.

Therefore you can say the following in reference to the event.

> 아침 때 보다. (*To see at breakfast*, but not <strike>*to see in the morning*</strike>.)
>   점심 때 보다. (*To see at lunch*.)

In sum, 아침 때 and 점심 때 have only one usage, i.e. *at breakfast* or *at lunch*; but 저녁 때 has two, i.e. *at supper* or *in the evening*.

Again remember I did not say 때 was a conjunction or preposition; only that they might be a convenient comparison.